# Type mismatch on err

Tags: vba, ms-access, types, error-handling

I'm using `GoTo` for error handling in an Access module and am getting a `type mismatch` error on the `Procedures.HandleError` call.

I tested to see if `err` is an Error:

```
Exit Sub
catch:
    If IsError(err) Then
        MsgBox "yes"
    Else
        MsgBox "no"
    End If
    Procedures.HandleError "ctrCreateSubject, frm_OnCreate", err, True
End Sub
```

and the `MsgBox` displays `no` and I can't figure out why. I'm using the same syntax in other places without problems

Can anyone help?

Comment: There's no such thing in Access `IsError(err)`. You need to query the `Err.Number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand a bit on my comment with an example.

The `On Error GoTo` statement will take care of the `IsError()` part since the procedure will jump to the `catch` label, **only** if there's an error. Therefore, if we do jump into the error handler, then we definitely have an error.

A sample error handler:

```
Sub Whatever()
    On Error GoTo catch

    'do something

Leave:
    Exit Sub

catch:
    'If we hit this point, then we definitely have an error.
    'At this point, we can query the error number if we want to take action based on the error.
    If Err.Number = xxxx Then
        Msgbox "Error " & xxxx
    End If
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

---

Then, there's another approach if you want to suspend the error handler and then query if an error occurred.

```
On Error Resume Next

'do something

If Err.Number <> 0
    'An error occurred
End If
```

Which we can then clear if we want to do this again later on on our method.

```
Err.Clear
```

Lastly, keep in mind `Err` is a global object so you don't need to create an instance. Further info on MSDN: [Err object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/err-object)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Just wondering why you wrote `Resume Leave` to exit the sub if the next line is `End Sub` anyway? Does it make a difference to the execution if the sub exits naturally after an error?

Comment: That is if you have any clean-up work to be done upon exiting, e.g close a connection, release a file handle etc. In addition, the keyword `Resume` resets all properties of the global Error object and can be called only within the error handler (the exit sub does the same).